# Android 6+ Volley requests blocked in background after 5 minutes if device is not plugged

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using Volley to send 'notifications' (think about it as "I'm here !")  every minute from my app to my web server using a web service (in POST). Everything was fine with Android 5.1, but on Android 6 and 7 requests seems to be blocked when my app is in background after about 5 minutes, when the device is not plugged. 5 or 6 first notifications are sent (app in background unplugged).

I first thought of a cache problem on the device side because the URL I use is always the same, so I disabled cache in Volley, and I added a timestamp to be sure the url varies each time. No change.

I then logged on the device, this is the error I get:

> com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

and after a while :

> com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort

I have a 30s timeout, max retries = 3, backoff multiplier = 1

No error when the device is plugged, my wifi is on, I don't think it's a network problem. Seems like Android is blocking data in background, but Data Saver is off on my device.

Pending notifications are sent if I turn screen on, if they haven't been cancelled yet (I think).

Comment: read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

Comment: Seems that's exactly what i was looking for !!! Thank you !!!

Comment: Happy to help you.